# Determine if process has restarted

Tags: redhat, systemd

How can we find out if a process has been restarted ever?
And if possible the total number of times it has been restarted?

The closest I got to this is

```
sudo journalctl -b -u <processname> | grep "Started"
```

Why do we need to find the above? 
A) To repopulate the process's memory from a local DB 
B) To take recovery actions if this process has been restarted too many times.

Are there are alternate ways to achieve the above two?

=Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't each service use a start/stop script in init.d/ folder? If you modify that script for the service you want to count number of restarts for, then just add a line in there to count and output to plain file.